# $_FILES empty on created_{taxonomy} and create_{taxonomy} yet is is not on edit_{taxonomy}

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

been struggling with a bug. On created_{taxonomy} hook yet in edited_{taxonomy} hook works and upload the expected file with no issues.
As per the following code I added custom field type along with custom taxonomy type. works fine.

```
add_action( 'init', 'addingCustomType' ); 


function addingCustomType() { 
    register_post_type( 'work', 
        array( 
            'labels' => array( 
                'name' => 'Works', 
                'singular_name' => 'work', 
                'add_new' => 'Add New', 
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work', 
                'edit' => 'Edit', 
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Work', 
                'new_item' => 'New Work', 
                'view' => 'View', 
                'view_item' => 'View Work', 
                'search_items' => 'Search Works', 
                'not_found' => 'No Works found', 
                'not_found_in_trash' =>  
                    'No Works found in Trash', 
                'parent' => 'Parent Work'                     
            ), 
            'public' => true, 
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rest_base'    => 'works',
            'menu_position' => 20, 
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ), 
            'taxonomies' => array( 'work_type' ), 
            'menu_icon' =>  
                plugins_url( 'works.png', __FILE__ ), 
            'has_archive' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true 
        ) 
    );

    register_taxonomy( 
        'work_type',       
        'work',                  
        array( 
            'labels' => array( 
                'name' => 'Work Type', 
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work Type', 
                'new_item_name' => 'New Work Type Name'
            ), 
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_tagcloud' => false, 
            // 'hierarchical' => true,
            'public' => true, 
            // 'show_in_rest' => true,
            // 'rest_base'    => 'work_type',
        )
    ); 
}
```

As per the following code is to add enctype on both edit and add(new)to my custom taxonomy (work_type) works fine it is visible in both forms.

```
add_action('work_type_term_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form' );
add_action('work_type_term_new_form_tag', 'update_edit_form' );

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

As per the following code is to add upload file input field to the admin panel on both scenario add & edit which works great.

```
add_action( 'work_type_edit_form_fields', 'ch4_br_book_type_new_fields', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'work_type_add_form_fields', 'ch4_br_book_type_new_fields', 10, 2 );


function ch4_br_book_type_new_fields( $tag ) {
    $mode = is_object( $tag ) ? 'edit' : 'new';
   

    switch($mode) {
        case 'edit': 
            // icon
            echo '<div class="form-field">';
            echo '<label for="tag-category-url">Choose an icon</label>';
            echo '<input type="file" id="typeIcon" name="typeIcon">';
            echo '</div>';  
      

        break;
        case 'new':
            // icon
            echo '<div class="form-field">';
            echo '<label for="tag-category-url">Choose an icon</label>';
            echo '<input type="file" id="typeIcon" name="typeIcon">';
            echo '</div>';  
        break;
    }
}
```

As per the following code I'm trying to use wp upload funtion to upload the file which works great in edited_{taxonomy} hook. However it is not working in created/create_{taxonomy} hook & $_FILES being empty with file['error'] = "Specified file failed upload test."

```
add_action( 'edited_work_type', 'ch4_br_save_book_type_new_fields', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'created_work_type', 'ch4_br_save_book_type_new_fields', 10, 2 );
function ch4_br_save_book_type_new_fields( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   

    if ( !$term_id ) {
        return;
    }

  
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES["typeIcon"];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    $iconFile  = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ($iconFile['error']) { 
        print_r($iconFile['error']);
        // print_r("file", $_FILES);
    }

    $returnvalue =  update_term_meta( $term_id, 'work_type_icon', $iconFile );
  
}
```

Anyone have an idea where does this behavior come from? is there a better hook to trigger taxonomy creation as it sound to me create & created hooks reset $_FILES?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a half answer, but I wanted to share my findings.

When adding a new term via the Add Term screen `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=work_type&post_type=work`, AJAX is being used and it is not handling the `$_FILES` array, so it is empty.

If you disable JS in your browser temporarily, then reload the page, add a new tag along with an image, then you can see that `$_FILES` is now populated when debugging.

The AJAX is being handled using `\wp-admin\js\tags.js`. Looking further in here, we can see that the $_FILES array is not being sent over with `$.post(ajaxurl, $('#addtag').serialize(), function(r)`.

I'm not sure of the best way to get around this. One way would be to unwire WP's AJAX handler, then create your own using the original handler as a starting point, but this is really not ideal.

While researching, I came across the [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin, which takes a different approach, by adding a UI next to each added term that allows you to upload an image.